# How to resolve '[info] server seems busy' from apache server logs?

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, httpd.conf, performance-tuning

I've seen this question asked a few times but it hasn't had any real answer; so I've decided to post my resolution.

The below `info` message can be seen in the apache error.log:

`[info] server seems busy, (you may need to increase StartServers, or Min/MaxSpareServers), spawning 16 children, there are 41 idle, and 129 total children`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resolution seems to be quite obvious; increase the `StartServers` until it goes away. While true, it is bad practice to arbitrarily increase the value unless you understand the implications and if the increased value is actually going to help.

I was reading over the httpd source code and it says the following:

```
/*
 * idle_spawn_rate is the number of children that will be spawned on the
 * next maintenance cycle if there aren't enough idle servers.  It is
 * doubled up to MAX_SPAWN_RATE, and reset only when a cycle goes by
 * without the need to spawn.
 */
```

Further in the source the actual error is logged when:

```
if (retained->idle_spawn_rate >= 8) {
                ap_log_error(APLOG_MARK, APLOG_INFO, 0, ap_server_conf, APLOGNO(00162)
                    "server seems busy, (you may need "
                    "to increase StartServers, or Min/MaxSpareServers), "
                    "spawning %d children, there are %d idle, and "
                    "%d total children", retained->idle_spawn_rate,
                    idle_count, total_non_dead);
            }
```

So what this means is; this error is thrown **when the number of children to be spawned at the next cycle is greater than 8 because there aren't enough servers to handle requests.**

So how can you fix it?

Each time this error is thrown you'll see something like `spawning 16 children`; this means that 16 children had to be spawned because there was a lack of servers to handle requests. Basically, increase your `StartServers` by the amount of spawning children until the error goes away. You can also increase the `Min/MaxSpareServers` by this amount instead.